# How to get the HTTP request of python -m x.wsgi?

Tags: python, django, django-wsgi

In my Server, I use

```
SCREEN -d -m python3 -m Qn02.wsgi
```

running my project, I can see by `ps -ef | grep python3`

```
root      2285     1  0 20:42 ?        00:00:00  SCREEN -d -m python3 -m Qn02.wsgi
```

but I have a question, that's how to see the requests from client?

Use the `python3 -m x.wsgi`, how to get the HTTP request log? or current HTTP request?

Comment: What are you doing with this? That is not how you run a Django project, either in development or in production.

Comment: Yeah, I mean if use this command to run the project, how to check logs or current request?

Comment: But as I say that is not how you run Django projects. Why are you doing it?